# How to identify a nodejs instance

Tags: node.js, express

I have a nodejs app (express application) and I running multiple instances of this same app. I want to uniquely name/identify each  one of this instances so at the moment what I am doing is to generate a fixed name + its pid, this way I get something like "mynodejsapp-#10293". The thing is now I would need a name that stays the same after every restart (so I do not want to use the pid anymore) but is still unique and automaticaly generated for each instance.
Does anyone have an idea if it would be possible and how I might achieve that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How would you associate with an existing instance after restart?

Comment: by its name. The problem I am trying to solve is: i have an external application that tracks performance of the node app. Today this external application retrieves a "name" (currently defined on the node app side using the pid) from the node instance. The problem is that when its restarted, pid changes and I lose track of the historical data. If I am able to use any other info (other than pid) that is unique on every instance but is the same after restarting it I would be able to keep track of that data even after the restart (same name/id)... Not sure if it would be somehow possible

Comment: You need to define what it means to "restart" and make some link to the old instance (maybe a command-line parameter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an environment variable declared right before each deployed instance i.e.:

```
user$ INSTANCE_ID=1 node app.js
```

which you can then access via `process.env`

Comment: yea I think Ill end up doing something like that. Thanks buddy